# Encrypting framework.server.password in Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

In Rundeck in the path /rundeck/etc
we have the file:
framework.properties

which has the parameter should have only plain text 
framework.server.password

The issue here is to encrypt it like we can do it for the following file in the path /rundeck/server/config:

realm.properties

Do we have a workaround to mask the plaintext password in framework.properties?

Answer (score 2):

the password in framework.properties is only used by the commandline tools to communicate with the server.  As an alternative you can remove the password from that file, and specify environment variables as shown here http://rundeck.org/docs/man1/cli-tool-authentication.html#environment-variables

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. But I want to use encrypted form in  command line tools also. So I believe this feature is not enabled.